# demystifying cordova build

Tags: cordova

After issuing a `cordova build --release android` command, an apk file is generated. Inside it, there's an AndroidManifest.xml file that contains the following line:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.google.android.gms.measurement.google_measurement_service" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider"/>
```

I don't have add any gms plugin, so I'm not sure why this line is there. This line prevents me from running the same apk with different versions (dev, debug, production).
How can I track what causes this line to be added?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: this was a while ago. I upgraded everything and it works. can't remember what exactly.